# IoT Data Storage Best Practice

Tags: mongodb, analytics, iot

Fairly new to analytics and looking for some guidance on how to store data in a MongoDB to be analysed in the future.

An example would be a temperature sensor that reports once every 10 minutes. After 1 year, we would like to run a report that shows the temperature over time.

Would a new document be created every time a new value is reported?

```
{
  id: 'xyz',
  date : "Sat May 05 2018 00:00:00",
  value: 20.0,
  unit: 'Celsius'
},

{
  id: 'xyz',
  date : "Sat May 05 2018 00:10:00",
  value: 19.0,
  unit: 'Celsius'
}
```

Or would one document get updated with the new information?

```
{
  _id: 'xyz',
  values:[
    {
      date : "Sat May 05 2018 00:00:00",
      value: 20.0,
      unit: 'Celsius'
    },
    {
      date : "Sat May 05 2018 00:10:00",
      value: 19.0,
      unit: 'Celsius'
    }
  ]
}
```

[upset and $inc](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/using-mongodb-for-real-time-analytics) look useful. But seem to overwrite the old values.

Comment: I would advise a new document for every record. If you keep appending to the same document, then you might hit the MongoDB Document limit (16MB) - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/. You also need to consider your granularity for old data. Do you really need 10 minute granularity for data 9 months ago? Or is hourly ok? And for reference - if you wanted to append to a list, then you can use the `$push` operator.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Just what I was looking for.

Comment: The update every 10 minutes is just an example. For some devices, updates will come in at random based on user interaction (like turning a light on and off).

Comment: If the data is recorded sporadically consider using a size-based bucketing strategy.  By issuing upserts you can control how many items in the array to include per document.  In my example in this document: https://www.mongodb.com/collateral/time-series-best-practices.  I create a new document every 200 entries or 1 day whichever comes first.

Comment: The time series best practices document was extremely helpful. Thank you @RobertWalters !